# HTTP 400 when inserting new subscription for Google Apps Marketplace application

Tags: google-api-java-client, google-apps-marketplace

I'm trying to insert a new subscription mainly to change the *seatCount* for the license. 
I'm using v2 licensing API and here is the code :

```
AppsMarketService service = new AppsMarketService();
service.appId = "appID";
service.appName = "someDomain";
service.endpoint = "https://www.googleapis.com/appsmarket/v2/";
service.consumerKey = service.appId + ".apps.googleusercontent.com";
service.consumerSecret = "somethingSecret";
service.authorize();

CustomerLicense cl = service.getCustomerLicense("company.com", true);

Subscription sub = new Subscription();
sub.subscriptionId = "subID";
sub.applicationId = service.appId;
sub.name = "Full";
sub.description = "Full service";
sub.currencyCode = "USD";
sub.customerId = cl.customerId;
sub.initialCart = new InitialCart();
sub.initialCart.cart = new Cart();
sub.initialCart.cart.receiptName = "Receipt name";
sub.initialCart.cart.receiptDescription = "Receipt description";

LineItem item = new LineItem();
item.name = "My Subscription";
item.description = "Subscription billing for the App";
item.editionId = "default_edition";
item.seatCount = 100; 
item.price = 100L;

sub.initialCart.cart.items = new ArrayList<LineItem>();
sub.initialCart.cart.items.add(item);

Subscription response = service.insertSubscription(sub);
```

It is very similar to the example provided [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/marketplace/billing#free-trial-java) except I didn't set the purchase token because I don't have it. No one has made a purchase yet.
I've debbuged the *insertSubscription* call down to the *HttpRequest.execute()* and the response is :

```
-------------- RESPONSE --------------
400
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Date: Thu, 02 May 2013 18:44:07 GMT
Content-Length: 139
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Expires: Thu, 02 May 2013 18:44:07 GMT
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Server: GSE
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0

02.05.2013. 20.44.07 com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: /licensing: com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 400
```

So basically there's no error message saying what went wrong. Any clues?

P.S. Showing how to update the default edition of the license would also be helpful.

Comment: We (Google) has released a new experience for the Google Apps Marketplace ([see announcement](http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com/2013/11/third-party-apps-now-easier-to-find-and.html)). The API is no longer valid - though we have a replacement coming shortly. You can read details in our [Developer Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/).